# C++ Consume API REST with Casablanca and POST XML

Tags: c++, xml, rest, casablanca

The question is how to consume API REST that needs to POST content on body type XML and on headers parameters. I found only solutions with JSON.

```
return pplx::create_task([]
{
    json::value postData;

    postData[L"name"] = json::value::string(L"Joe Smith");
    postData[L"hobby"] = json::value::string(L"Baseball");

    http_client client(L"http://localhost:5540/api/values");
    return client.request(methods::POST, L"",
        postData.to_string().c_str(), L"application/xml");
}).then([](http_response response)
{
    if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
    {
        auto body = response.extract_string();
        std::wcout << L"Added new Id: " << body.get().c_str() << std::endl;

        return std::stoi(body.get().c_str());
    }

    return 0;
});
```

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the library. Using libcurl with no problem and it's easier.